# App crashes when I entered nothing on edittext

Tags: java, android

What's missing in code?

I have a problem here. I have here 2 edittext. One for amount and one for password. My app works like a charm except when I entered NONE on the edittexts, IT CRASHES (Unfortunately stop). Am I missing any code on my activity? Please help. Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button REDIRECT;
    private EditText txtbox1,txtbox2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        REDIRECT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        txtbox1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        txtbox2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        REDIRECT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int Amount = Integer.parseInt(txtbox1.getText().toString());
                String Password = txtbox2.getText().toString();


                if(Amount<=50&&Amount>=1 & Password.equals("TUBOL"))
                {

                final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Redirect.class);               
                startActivity(i);
                }
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at com.example.pwordlockdown.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-15 01:46:34.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30540):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Krev post logcat its just a minor error

Comment: please, prevent usage of Upper case variables, like `Button REDIRECT;` and  `int Amount`

Comment: the LogCat is very obvious: NumberFormatException, you are parsing an empty String to an int, which crashes your app, the right answers have been downvoted in this thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an uncaught `NumberFormatExpection` on `Integer.parseInt(txtbox1.getText().toString())`

`txtbox1` is empty when this method is called, so you're calling `Integer.parseInt("")` which throws a `NumberFormatExpection`.

Comment: Most probably, the code won't reach that point and fail with an NPE.

Comment: @shoe before applying your probability first read the question

Comment: @shoerat the logcat shows this was exactly the problem - please consider retracting your downvote!

Comment: @davnicwil yeah *probable* NPE

Comment: @davnicwil you won :P

Answer (score 3):

You are entering String and trying to parse it to Int

```
int Amount = 0;

try
{
    Amount = Integer.parseInt(txtbox1.getText().toString());
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    // Sep 14, 2013 11:26:26 PM
    Log.e("Exception","DownloadFileTask.onPostExecute.NumberFormatException"+String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This **throwing error**

You must use for number only **EditText** set property `inputType`
 like this

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Most probably, the code won't reach that point and fail with an NPE.

Comment: I will find what? :) Anyhow, I'd not jump to post an answer without seeing the stack trace...

Comment: It's clear as water if you parse "NOne" it won't be parsed to INTEGER don't you find this as an Bug

Comment: User already said the condition read the question before reading the stacktrace

Comment: What would be the best solution for that?

Comment: you must use the EditText number only

Answer (score 1):

Check if the input is not null before converting Amount it to **int** otherwise there will be **NumberFormatException**

```
 REDIRECT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String a=txtbox1.getText().toString();
        if(a.equals(" "))
        {

        Toast a1 =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the Amount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        a1.show();

        }
        else 
    {

    int Amount = Integer.parseInt(txtbox1.getText().toString());
            String Password = txtbox2.getText().toString();


            if(Amount<=50&&Amount>=1 & Password.equals("TUBOL"))
            {

            final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Redirect.class);               
            startActivity(i);
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if nothing is entered into the `EditText`, then parsing it to an `Integer` would give you an error (because there are no numbers to parse).

When taking input from your `EditText` and parsing it to an `Integer`, simply add an `if` structure, like so:

```
if (!(editText.getText().toString().equals(""))) // if edit text is NOT blank
{
    int num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to catch the possible errors thrown by trying to parse the `txtBox1..getText().toString()` and just rout it back to the error toast?

Answer (score 0):

hey you gotta do an if statement to check if the `textBox` is empty or not...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button REDIRECT;
private EditText txtbox1,txtbox2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    REDIRECT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txtbox1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
    txtbox2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    REDIRECT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!txtbox1.getText().toString().equals("")){

            int Amount = Integer.parseInt(txtbox1.getText().toString());
            String Password = txtbox2.getText().toString();


            if(Amount<=50&&Amount>=1 & Password.equals("TUBOL"))
            {

            final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Redirect.class);               
            startActivity(i);
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Amount Box empty...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

hope it helps...

Comment: don't you know the string comparison in java

Comment: sorry my bad....mixing things up....but hope it helps the OP in solving the problem

Answer (score -1):

I find my solution.
I set `android:text="0"` 
and my problem is gone. :))

Comment: please see my answer, even though it received downvotes for unknown reasons, it does in fact show exactly what the root problem is - the NumberFormatException due to empty string input to Integer.parseInt()

Comment: yeah, either catch and deal with the exception or check if the input is empty before attempting parseInt()- the former is better because it'll deal with all bad inputs not just the special empty case

Comment: this is not a solution, the user presses the delete key and your textview is empty again resulting in a crash. What you should do is first check for text.length() > 0, secondly try/catch the NumberFormatException

Comment: @Krev If you set android:text="0"  the user still could delete "0" and then press your button and youll get error

Comment: I know. I'm working on the NumberFormatException. And its not Krev, its KERV. :))

Comment: @Kerv you will have to check for empty and will have to surround with try catch to be sure for right input